# Como adicionar banners no Joomla a partir de módulos internos, sem plugins?

Tags: joomla

Eu estou tentando adicionar 3 banners no meu blog Joomla, mas não estou conseguindo encaixar o que quero fazer com os módulos do Joomla.Eu quero que o blog fique com a estrutura da imagem abaixo.[image: modelo que quero criar].

Eu não pretendo usar um módulo de terceiro, a menos que seja obrigatório. É possível fazer apenas com os módulos internos do Joomla ? Como ? Alguém pode me dá uma mão, please ?

Detalhe: Sou iniciante em Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

Essa estrutura requer um template com posições nas laterais.
Você pode tentar utiliza o Gantry do RocketTheme. Nesse template é possível utilizar essa estrutura sem conhecimento avançado de código fonte.
http://gantry.org/

Comment: Ola Max, seja bem vindo, poderia dar um exemplo de código fonte aqui para que toda a solução seja visível no site, e obrigado pela sua contribuição

Comment: Oi Sneep. Esse templante/componente que eu mencionei, o Gantry, não exige conhecimento de código fonte. É gratuito e pode ser instalado no Joomla. Depois de instalado, pode ser configurada a posição dos módulos exatamente como a pergunta do Josué. Como ele comentou que é iniciante, seria uma ótima alternativa.

Comment: Entendi, mas se o @Josué não sabe configurar o joomla, fazer uso do gantry sem nenhuma demonstração vai deixa-lo na mesma situação que ele já se encontra ( não domina a ferramenta )